# A proof about the limit infimum of a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I tried to find a proof for this statement: If we have a bounded sequence $x_n$, then the limit infimum is defined as $a=\liminf_n x_n$ such that $a$ is the largest of real numbers which have the property that for all $a' < a$ we have finitely many $x_n < a'$.

Intuitively I can see that this is valid: If we have a plot of a bounded sequence $x_n$ we draw a horizontal line $y=a' < a$ and there must be a finite number of $x_n$ points in the below of the line. But as soon as that line passes $y=a$ then the number $x_n$ points under the line becomes infinite. I have miserably failed to put this thought into a mathematically valid statement, so I turned here for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the definition of $\lim\inf$ that you use here?

Comment: Well, I only know about a single definition of the $\liminf$ which is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k \geq n} x_k$. The limit of the sequence of infimums of the subsequences $x_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the definitions of $\lim \inf$. There are several we may choose from, I will use the following definition of $\lim \inf$: Let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence and let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be the collection of all subsequential limits of $x_n$. We define $$a=\lim\inf x_n = \inf \{ x \in E \}$$

Now suppose there is an $a' < a$ for which there are infinitely many $n$ such that $x_n < a'$. This means there is a subsequence of $x_n$, call it $x_{n_k}$ for which $x_{n_k} < a'$ for all $k$. This subsequence is bounded, which means there is some subsequential limit. This limit can be at most $a'$, which is strictly less than $a$. This is a contradiction.

---

For the definition you requested it can be proved in a similar fashion. Suppose that there is an infinite number of $n$ for which $x_n < a' < a$. This means that for each $n$ there is a $k>n$ for which $x_k < a'$. Hence $y_n = \inf_{k>n} x_k < a'$ for all $n$. Now this sequence $y_n$ is upper bounded by $a'$, and $\lim\inf x_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} y_n \le a'$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: What is meant by the subsequential limits of $ x_n$ ?

Comment: The sequence $x_n$ has subsequences that converge. That doesn't mean the sequence itself does. For instance take $(-1)^n$ as our sequence. Two convergent subsequences are $(-1)^{2n}$ and $(-1)^{2n+1}$. The corresponding subsequential limits are 1 and -1 respectively.

Comment: Since each sequence of real numbers has a monotonic subsequence, and this sequence is a bounded sequence, there must be at least one convergent subsequence of $x_n$. Therefore we know the collection of subsequential limits is nonempty.

Comment: This is due to the Weistrass Bolzano theorem right? It says that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: By the way; is it possible to prove this with the first definition of $\liminf $ which is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k \geq n} x_k $?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: By the way you should be writing: $\lim\inf x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{k\ge n} x_k$

Comment: Ah yes I corrected that.